# Rails join collection not recognizing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a record in a join table named Interventions. Basically in my application a user can do many interventions on an incident, and an incident can have interventions by many users. I pass the needed strong parameters, but the application gives the following errors when I try to save: "Incident must exist" and "User must exist". I spent hours on this, and can't figure out what is the problem. Can you please help me? I post the relevant code here:

```
user.rb (model)
  has_many :interventions
  has_many :incidents, through: :interventions

incident.rb (model)
  has_many :interventions
  has_many :users, through: :interventions

intervention.rb (model)
  belongs_to :incident_priority
  belongs_to :intervention_status
```

interventions_controller.rb

```
def new

  @incident = Incident.find(params[:incident])
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @intervention = Intervention.new(:user_id => @user, :incident_id => @incident)

  @project = @incident.channel.project
  @mirth = Mirth.find_by server_id: @incident.mirth_server_id
end


def create
  @incident = Incident.find(params[:incident_id])
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @intervention = Intervention.create(intervention_params)

  @project = @incident.channel.project
  @mirth = Mirth.find_by server_id: @incident.mirth_server_id

  respond_to do |format|
    if @intervention.save
      format.html { redirect_to new_intervention_path(@incident), notice: 'Intervention was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @intervention }
    else
      format.html { render :new, incident: :incident_id }
      format.json { render json: @intervention.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

< .... >

def intervention_params
  params.require(:intervention).permit(:user_id, :incident_id, :incident_priority_id, :begin_date, :end_date, :description,
                                       :intervention_status_id, :forwarded_to)
end
```

In my view (interventions_form.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for(@intervention) do |f| %>
<% if @intervention.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@intervention.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this intervention from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @intervention.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<div class="form-group form-inline">

  <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :incident_id, @incident.id %>

  <strong>Interveniente:</strong>
  <%= @user.first_name %> <%= @user.last_name %>

</div>

<div class="form-group form-inline">
  <%= f.label 'Prioridade' %>
  <%= f.collection_select :incident_priority_id, IncidentPriority.all, :id, :description, {}, {class: "form-control"} %>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-inline">
  <%= f.label 'Data início intervenção' %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :begin_date %>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-inline">
  <%= f.label 'Data fim intervenção' %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :end_date, :include_blank => true  %>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-inline">
  <%= f.label 'Observações' %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-inline">
  <%= f.label 'Estado' %>
  <%= f.collection_select :intervention_status_id, InterventionStatus.all, :id, :description, {}, {class: "form-control"} %>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-inline">
  <%= f.label 'Encaminhado para:' %>
  <%= f.text_area :forwarded_to %>
</div>

<div class="actions" align="right">
  <%= link_to 'Voltar', incidents_path(:mirth => @mirth, :project => @project), class: "btn btn-info" %>
  <%= f.submit "Gravar", class: "btn btn-info" %>
</div>
```

I run debug and the values in the hidden_field_tags are correctly filled. Also in the controller the @user and @incident are correctly populated, but @intervention has nil in the foreign keys :user_id and :incident_id.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when setting `user_id` here `@intervention = Intervention.new(:user_id => @user, :incident_id => @incident)` either do `@user.id` or simply set `user: @user` same goes for incident. see if that works

Comment: I made that change, but it gives the same errors :/

Comment: answer to this question is essentially the same thing as I suggested. :) glad it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate the user and the incident with the intervention.

in your model...

```
class Intervention
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :incident
```

in your create method...

```
def create
  @incident = Incident.find(params[:incident_id])
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @intervention = Intervention.create(intervention_params)
  @intervention.incident = @incident
  @intervention.user = @user
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
def create
  @incident = Incident.find(params[:incident_id])
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])

  # ...
end
```

For this:

```
def create
  @incident = Incident.find(params[:incident_id])
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  intervention_params.merge(user_id: @user.id, incident_id: @incident.id)

  # ...
end
```

And your model:

```
class Intervention
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :incident
```

Comment: SteveTurczyn solution solved the problem, thank you so much anyway!